# MySQL group_concat SEPARATOR char or ascii

Tags: mysql, group-concat, non-printing-characters

Is there a way in MySQL to define a SEPARATOR in group_concat() with a non printable sign? Like ascii 3 or something like that?

i tried

```
group_concat(text SEPARATOR char(3))
```

and

```
group_concat(text SEPARATOR 3)
```

both of them doesn´t work.

Maybe a way to escaping?

I get long texts and i want to be sure that no printable sign will destroy my content. So i want to seperate them with a non printable sign...

any ideas?

Comment: What is the reason to group then split back? Like, why to do the unnecessary job at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a way!
e.g. you want to seperat with ascii 3, you have to use:

```
group_concat(text SEPARATOR 0x3)
```

Comment: Sry, too fast fingers.

Comment: Ok, it was a manual typo then, that's why... Good that it works!